# How to determine impelimantation of which interface was missed during registration in DryIoc?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, dryioc

How to find the interface name that is not registered but needed?

I just get this Error:


Type 'Test.TestController' does not have a default constructor


but I need name of missed Interface because some of them have multi level interface in constractors


I Use this extensions:

- DryIoc.dll v4.0.7
- DryIoc.WebApi.dll v4.0.0
- DryIoc.Web.dll v4.0.0
- DryIoc.Mvc.dll v4.0.0

In the WebApi:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var container = new Container().WithWebApi(config, throwIfUnresolved: type => true);

        //...
    }
```

In the Mvc:

```
    public CustomControllerFactory()
    {
        Container = new Container().WithMvc(throwIfUnresolved: type => true);

        // ...
    }
```

Exception message is:

> DryIoc.ContainerException: 'Unable to resolve ModelMetadataProvider IsResolutionCall
>     from Container with ambient ScopeContext DryIoc.AsyncExecutionFlowScopeContext without Scope
>    Where no service registrations found
>     and no dynamic registrations found in 0 of Rules.DynamicServiceProviders
>     and nothing found in 0 of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers'

Comment: What DryIoc extension do you use?

Comment: DryIoc.WebApi v4.0.0 & DryIoc.Mvc v4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Both WithWebApi and WithMvc extension methods accept optional throwIfUnresolved parameter.

It can be used like this:

```
throwIfUnresolved: type => Debugger.IsAttached && type.Name.EndsWith("Controller")
```

This will instruct framework to throw original DryIoc exception in Debug mode.

Comment: I get this exception message:
DryIoc.ContainerException: 'Unable to resolve ModelMetadataProvider IsResolutionCall from Container with ambient ScopeContext DryIoc.AsyncExecutionFlowScopeContext without Scope Where no service registrations found and no dynamic registrations found in 0 of Rules.DynamicServiceProviders and nothing found in 0 of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers'

Comment: That means `ModelMetadataProvider` dependency is not found.